# Do all solutions to the Dirac equation transform as spinors?

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, field-theory, inertial-frames, dirac-equation

Usually, the Dirac equation is introduced as the equation $D \psi = 0$, which is form invariant under Lorentz transformations ($\Lambda$), when $\psi$ transforms as a spinor $\psi' \to S(\Lambda) \psi$. It is then shown from the properties of the $\gamma$ matrices that when $S(\Lambda) = \Lambda_{1/2}$, then $D' \to S(\Lambda) D S^{-1}(\Lambda)$, which completes the discussion.

However, I do not see why the Dirac equation, as a general PDE, only has spinor solutions. Under a Lorentz transformation, it is easily shown that

$$D\psi = 0 \to \Lambda_{1/2} D \Lambda_{1/2}^{-1} \psi' = 0$$

This only implies that $\Lambda_{1/2}^{-1} \psi'$ is 'a solution' to the Dirac equation, but not the stronger condition that $\Lambda^{-1}_{1/2} \psi' = \psi$, which is what we need to say that all solutions transform as spinors.

Comment: Hint: linear PDEs have existence and uniqueness theorems. If $\psi$ and $\psi'$ both solve the same equation, and satisfy the same boundary conditions, then...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This answers my question! Wondering if I should close the question.